# A special switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, setjmp

I am reading CSAPP, the chapter about `setjmp` and `longjmp`, and encounter the following code snippets:

```
int rc;
switch(setjmp(buf));
if (rc == 0)
    foo();
else if (rc == 1)
    printf("sth.");
else if (rc == 2)
    printf("sth. other");
...
```

The switch statement really confused me, could someone explain this usage of switch statement in C for me?

---

PS: This is actually an error of CSAPP(the second edition), and the author fixes this by using normal `switch-case` statement in the third edition. Thanks for all.

Comment: Your `printf` statements need some `;` lovin'.

Comment: They love double quotes, too...

Comment: Mind you, there's nothing like a 32 bit implementation defined character array like `'sth.'`

Comment: There's no assignment being done to `rc` yet its value being compared.  Are you sure this is the **exact** code you found?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, please note that `setjmp` and `longjmp` are considered incredible poor practice to use, the worst kind of spaghetti programming. Any source of learning teaching you to use these functions should be regarded with great scepticism.

---

As for the reason why the weird switch statement is there, it is because of a number of artificial requirements placed on the `setjmp` function by the standard. C11 7.13.1.1

> Environmental limits  An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear
>   only in one of the following contexts:
>   — the entire controlling
>   expression of a selection or iteration statement;
>   — one operand of a
>   relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer
>   constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire
>   controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
>   — the operand of a unary ! operator with the resulting expression being the entire
>   controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; or
>   — the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).

Please note that the last point above allows code such as `(void) setjmp(env);`, so the switch statement in the question is mostly obfuscation.

The C standard rationale 7.13.1 provides an explanation of why this "function" has such artificial requirements, namely because it must be implemented as a macro:

> 7.13.1.1 The setjmp macro
>   One proposed requirement on setjmp is that it be usable like any other function, that is, that it be callable
>   in any expression context, and that the expression evaluate correctly
>   whether the return from setjmp is direct or via a call to longjmp.
>   Unfortunately, any implementation of setjmp as a conventional called
>   function cannot know enough about the calling environment to save any
>   temporary registers or dynamic stack locations used part way through
>   an expression evaluation. (A setjmp macro seems to help only if it expands to inline assembly code or a call
>   to a special built-in function.) The temporaries may be correct on the initial call to setjmp, but
>   are not likely to be on any return initiated by a corresponding call to longjmp. These
>   considerations dictated the constraint that setjmp be called only from within fairly simple expressions, ones not likely to need temporary storage.

To put it plainly: if you would call a function instead of a macro, then the CPU/OS might stack away various registers that you actually want setjmp to preserve, most notably the program counter. (setjmp was specified long before the C language supported inline functions.)

Answer (score 4):

It's someone being cute: the *documentation* of the C-standard library function `setjmp` reveals that the function can only be used in a small number of places; the *controlling expression* of a `switch` being one of them.

`switch(setjmp(buf));` doesn't actually do anything other than call the function `setjmp(buf)`. The *body* of the `switch` is the empty statement `;`

Note that the considerably less obtuse

```
setjmp(buf);
```

is also valid. Perhaps the author uses the `switch` obfuscation to signal that they are doing something out of the ordinary.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/setjmp

Comment: What in the actual... Also they say it can be *the entire expression of an expression statement*, so that's absolutely unnecessary anyway.

Comment: cute is one term.

Comment: Personally,I don't think that linking to a **C++** documentation site is appropiate, especially not in sensitive (fragile) areas like this.

Comment: It does purport to treat C too, and my specific link is a C page. If you know of a correspondingly "canonical" reference for C then do please let me know.

Comment: Why, the C specific documentation on cppreference, of course. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp Is linked to at the bottom of the page for the C++ documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `setjmp` outside a conditional check location, when a `longjmp` is called then the execution is resumed at the `setjmp` location stored in the `buf` parameter, returning the value passed to `longjmp`. I believe that who wrote the code just needed a conditional check location that did nothing, hence the empty `switch`.

To know more check the POSIX reference page that provides the documentation for the function as stated in the ISO C standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html

Also the manpage for longjmp(3) seems to provide more in-depth information: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html

**[Edit]**

Huh, it actual looks like you can call it outside a conditional check, specifically "The entire expression of an expression statement". I do not know why they did it, even though I understand why it would be best called in a conditional, so you can check its return value from wherever you jumped from.

Comment: You can call it as (from C11) "the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void)". I would suspect they wanted to avoid weird cases of poorly defined order of evaluation, such as `foo = setjmp(env1) | setjmp(env2)`.

Comment: Yup, that seems about right. I did not think about using it that way, actually. It looks like looking for troubles :)

Comment: Mh, yeah, you are right. It's a quirk due to the fact that I work with C++. Let me get a better reference.

Comment: I found out the real rationale and it turns out it is because they can't implement it as a function. I posted a separate answer with a quote from the C rationale.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thanks for the contribution, and yes, it smells like  spaghetti-code.